# adding friends in a while loop

Tags: php

My problem started on the members page of my website where i used a `while` loop do display all members.

```
$X_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($X_query)) {
  $X_id = $row['X'];
  $X_firstname = $row['X'];
  $X_lastname = $row['X'];
  $X_regdate = $row['X'];
  $X_ocupation = $row['X'];
  $X_gender = $row['X'];
  $X_main_proff = $row['X']; 

  if ($X_id == $id) { //the second is the SESSION ID
    $add_frined_button .= "";
  }
  else {
    $add_frined_button .= '<tr>
      <td><a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:alertWindowFriend();"><div class="submit_buttons_blue" id="add_friend">addfriend</div></a></td>
      </tr>';
  }
```

This actually works good and the button handles the friend adding through jQuery and AJAX, but everything works wrong if I log with another user:

the ADD FRIEND button shows for him in the loop and although I made a check to see that, his session ID equals 2.
When I send a friend request it shows as user with ID 2 requesting friendship from himself.

I really don't know what is the problem here, and if someone has a clue or needs to see more code like the friend request process, I will post it here.

Comment: Are you sure that the session variables are being updated correctly when you logout / login as somebody else?

Comment: where does $X come from (the variable used in the comparison with $id)? It doesn't seem to be initialized in the code shown. You should improve the indentation - the "frined" button part is in the loop after all (and thus should be indented just as the lines starting with "$X_"...

Comment: what is `$x` in `if`statement? Are you sure its not `$x_id`?

Comment: Also, you are setting `$X_id` but then checking `$X == $id`... should that actually be `$X_id == $id`?

Comment: Where do `$X` and `$id` exactly come from? Also: How do you pass the ID of the person you weant to be friends with to the JavaScript (don't see anything in the link)? And, btw., all your DIVs have the same `id="add_friend"`which you should change.

Comment: $X => the id from the while loop $id => id of the SESSION, once again the code works for my user but not for other users

Comment: Hint: Add `'.$X_id.' == '.$id.'` after the `<td>` of `$add_frined_button` to see what values those vars actually have.

Comment: i did this already, they display the correct values :\

Comment: You might want to edit your question and add the output you get. If the values that are displayed in the `<td>` are not equal then your code is correct and there should be to button for the user that is logged in.

Comment: ok i did as you said and indeed in the while in both users rows i get the same values 1 for id and 2 for the loop id...why could this be happening? adn this only happens when i log in with the usr with id 2, the user with id 1 works good.

Comment: the first javascript functions displayed in my post just fires up an alert window in wich when the yuser confirms i pass 2 vars a,b by echoing the id and the x_id to the functions then with the ajax post i send them to the parse file.

Answer (score 1):

Change

`if ($X == $id) { //the second is the SESSION ID`

To

`if ($X_id == $id) { //the second is the SESSION ID`

And magic shall happen :)

Comment: sorry for the miss understanding. the $X var IS the id from the while loop just didnt want to show my real var names.